# Is there a way to convert a website to a PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing, website

I made a simple "website" which looks like a quotation, and I can modify values easily through Javascript, it has no images (just a logo but is SVG). I want to convert this to a PDF, so I can print it, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is right clicking the page and selecting `Print` an option?

Comment: There are lots of browser add-ons and web sites that do exactly that.  You can also just print the page to a PDF printer driver.  Some screen/page capture utilities also include the option to select everything, including what isn't displayed within the window, and print it or save it as an image or PDF.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I tried it but it doesn't show background-colors, or text color, it show all backgrounds white, and their colors light-gray

Comment: @fixer1234 I tried a lot of extensions and all just take a screenshot and paste it into a PDF or do the same as the browser print option, which displays it bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after searching a lot I found this tool: https://www.sejda.com/es/html-to-pdf. Which was the only one that worked fine, waited for javascript to run, and displayed it accurately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a contiguous PDF with all pages as found by a human user, look at webshot.website. Their free trial is already sufficient in many cases. And if not, it is still cheap to get a more advanced one.

Comment: (1) Can you provide a bit more information about this? (2) Can you provide a reference that this is a reputable service?  McAfee doesn’t know whether it is safe. (3) Are you affiliated with this site? (E.g., employee — developer or salesman — or co-owner/stakeholder?) You have posted two answers recommending this site within three minutes, and they were your first two answers after joining the site. See [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: Well I did not intent to push their site. There might be others too, just that I did not find anything useful yet. The one I refered to is nice, but please let me know of others.